# How to initialize Automapper when source type is unknown

Tags: c#, types, initialization, automapper

I have following code:

```
public static TDest Map2<TDest>(this object sourceObjInstance) where TDest : new()
{
    var itemType = typeof(TDest);
    var item = Activator.CreateInstance(itemType);
    Mapper.Initialize((cfg => cfg.CreateMap<??????, TDest>());
    var result = Mapper.Map(sourceObjInstance, item, sourceObjInstance.GetType(), item.GetType());
    return (TDest)result;
}
```

So, I don't know where to get generic parameter (`?????` placeholder) for source object for mapper.initialize method. The `sourceObjInstance` will be autogenerated class by WCF.

Comment: 1- You shouldn't initialize each time you map. Initialize and create your mappings at your application startup. Then Map when you need to. 2- Always know what you map. Create one mapping for each type that need to be mapped to another one.

Answer (score 1):

Automapper supports dynamic mapping. Set `CreateMissingTypeMaps` configuration property when you don't know the source/destination type at compile time:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true);

object src = new Src();
object dest = new Dest();

Mapper.Map(src, dest);
```